# how to combine arlert and nagivation.navigate in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am having a project in React Native and i have a Signup screen. When i click into touchableopacity Sign up, it arlerts "Create Succesfully" then go to Login screen. How can I do that? I only know how to do either of them by using onPress. How can I combine it together? I use nagivation.navigate ("Login") to change the screen. Pls help me, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You show pop up "Create user successfully. You can log in now". When the user press ok button will navigation to Login Screen

```
// Works on both Android and iOS
Alert.alert(
  'Create user successfully',
  'You can log in now.....',
  [
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => nagivation.navigate ("Login")  }
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
);
```

Comment: cảm ơn anh, em sẽ thử ạ.

Comment: Alternatively, the dismissing behavior can be disabled altogether by providing an optional options parameter with the cancelable property set to false i.e. { cancelable: false }.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate after alert is dismissed then try below code.

```
Alert.alert(‘any title ’, ‘any description’,[{
text:’sign in’,
onPress:()=>navigation.navigate(‘your route’)
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call it like this:

```
onPress={()=> {
alert("Logged in Succesfully")
this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
}}
```

this way you have a Alert and your redirection in the same call if thats what you want.